# Anyone have a Working Example of a Facebook Share Button Using The Feed Dialog Method?

Tags: facebook, share

I have been looking around for a working example of a Facebook share button using the Feed Dialog method (method number 2 in this article:  http://www.phpied.com/speed-geeks-guide-to-facebook-buttons/)

Does anyone have a js fiddle with an example of this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's an example on the URL you linked, which works fine for me

Comment: i get a generic error with that one-- hoping to compare it with others

Answer (score 1):

The example you gave has an one being:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?link=jspatterns.com&amp;app_id=179150165472010&amp;redirect_uri=http://phpied.com">Share</a>
```

Or Facebook directly for greater detail
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.4